# Table <td> with content that does not match

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a Table meant for keeping a Log of exercises you have performed. The problem is that at the moment I can't seem to line up the content of the two different 's with each other.

Probably I'm using the wrong approach to achieve what I want.

This is what I am going for:

```
Date | Exercise | Result
------------------------------
Mon  | Sit-up   | I did 3 sets
     |          | of 15 reps
     |          | with an extra weight
     |          |
     | Push-up  | bladibladibla
---------------------------------
Tue  |          |
--------------------------------
Wed  |          |
-------------------------------
etc.
```

The result I am getting right now though is as follows:

```
Date | Exercise | Result
------------------------------
Mon  | Sit-up   | I did 3 sets
     | Push-up  | of 15 reps
     |          | with an extra weight
     |          | bladibladibla
---------------------------------
Tue  |          |
--------------------------------
Wed  |          |
-------------------------------
etc.
```

The html output of my PHP code is as follows:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Exercise</th>
            <th>Result</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>30/12/2019</td>
            <td>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li>sit-up</li>
                    <li>push-up</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li>I did 3 sets of 15 reps with an extra weight</li>
                    <li>Bladibladibladibla</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>31/12/2019</td>
            etc.
```

This is how I am making and printing my list:

```
$oefenlijst = "<ul class='list-unstyled'><li>" . implode("</li><li>", $oefeningen) . "</li></ul>";

$resultatenlijst = "<ul class='list-unstyled'><li>" . implode("</li><li>", $resultaten) . "</li></ul>";

echo "<td>" . date("d/m/Y", $d) . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $oefenlijst . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $resultatenlijst . "</td>";
```

I feel the problem are the lists but I don't know how else I should put the information in my table. I hope there is an easy fix for my problem that I'm just overlooking or I am just not aware of. You may also be wondering why I don't just make the table bigger but I'm working from a mobile pov.

I hope this enough info so you can answer my question.

Comment: it's probably how you're printing the lists from the php, you probably should specify that in order to get an answer for this question

Answer (score 0):

You get what you put in your HTML. In order to fix that, you can do several methods:

1. Change table to blocks and use CSS to style them (add `float` and `clear` for all blocks).
2. Get rid of lists, use cells and specify `td rowspan` attribute. Style your cells for borders.
3. Add styles to list elements. This approach will keep your structure unchanged, but you'll have some challenge to calculate the right height for all elements.
4. Research for the latest HTML5/CSS3 foundations to solve your issue